# How to play FM Radio app without earphone?

Tags: fm-radio

I would like to play my default FM Radio app. But it always asking to connect an earphone.

Is it possible to play FM Radio app without an earphone ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. You need an earphone, or anything that can plug into the earphone jack, with a trailing cable.

This is to provide the phone with an antenna. Because space inside the phone is highly limited, it's usually insensible to have a built-in FM antenna.

Usually, you can still instruct the phone (or at least the FM app) to output audio to its speaker, even when earphone is plugged in, as it's primary function is to serve as antennae.

Answer (score 0):

I use Tecno LC7 and I don't use antenna to listen to radio. So it's possible to have it as built-in

Comment: Is the app FM radio (that the stations' availability depends on the current location), or digital radio?

Comment: Looking at the Tecno specs online it appears that you do need an antenna.  Or am I missing something?

Comment: I never knew the phone was like that until I started using it, it even came with an earpiece

Comment: @Andrew. Yes, It's depends on the current location